# Javascript Protractor Compare summed promises

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

I'm trying to get 3 values from a webpage, sum 2 of them (currencies eg.$2,213.93) and compare if it equals the third value.

Protractor function locator.getText() returns a promise and I have to do all the conversions inside a promise

This is how I tried to do it

Get Value from a webpage and convert it:

```
    SettingsPage.prototype.getValueAndConvert = function (locator) {
        locator.getText().then(function (text) {
            numb = text.replace(/,/g, '');
            numb = numb.replace(/\$/g, '');
            numb= numb.replace(/\./g, '');
            numb = parseInt(numb);
            console.log(numb);
            return numb
         });
        };
```

Assert that the values are equal

```
            var workingBalancevalue = settings.getValueAndConvert(workingBalanceField);
            var totalInflowvalue = settings.getValueAndConvert(totalInflowField);
            var totalOutflowvalue = settings.getValueAndConvert(totalOutflowField);
            protractor.promise.all([totalInflowvalue, totalOutflowvalue, workingBalancevalue]).then(function (values) {
                expect((values[0]) + (values[1])).toEqual(values[2]);
            });
```

It works but the value of console.log(numb) in NaN so this is not true because is matches NaN to NaN

How to actually do it?

Comment: The `values` already are numbers, you should not `parseInt` them

Comment: Well if `numb` is `NaN`, then what is `text`? Please log them both.

Comment: Your `getValueAndConvert` method does not `return` the promise it should

Comment: the "text" is probably a string as the returned value is $2,213.93 so after the conversion with replace i should probably ParseInt? how should I return a good promise?

Comment: Yes, you should `parseInt` the sanitised `text` to a `numb`er, but you should not `parseInt` the `values[0]` etc. And if you're not sure whether it's a string - log it! (My guess would be that you get `NaN` because you failed to remove the `$` sign)

Comment: You'd make the method return the promise by simply filling in the missing `return` keyword

Comment: there is a method 'return numb', should i add something more? The type of text is string and console.log(text) returns a proper value. I've removed the parseInt from the expect function and now it returns Expected NaN to equal undefined, There is not a single $ inside whole project, all locators are based on XPATH

Comment: The `return numb` returns the number from the `then` callback function. You still have to return the promise that `.then()` creates from the `getValueAndConvert` method.

Comment: and how to do it in this scenario?

Comment: I managed to retreive the values of "numb" as int's without extra signs but still get this error when doing promise.all

Comment: As I said, just `return` the `locator.getText().then(…)` promise!

Comment: hahaha Its all working! thanks! :)

Comment: Why you remove the `.` in dollar string,  it makes the value wrong.   `$12.34` after converted by your function become `1234`, but expect `12.34`.

Comment: your right but i just want to compare the numbers, they dont have to be exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

the answer was to add return of a promise

```
 SettingsPage.prototype.getValueAndConvert = function (locator) {
        return locator.getText().then(function (text) {       // added return
            numb = text.replace(/,/g, '');
            numb = numb.replace(/\$/g, '');
            numb= numb.replace(/\./g, '');
            numb = parseInt(numb);
            console.log(numb);
            return numb
         });
        };
```